Apache Pulsar: Consumer will not register but produces a timeout
I'm trying to set up Pulsar for a .NET 6.0 application. Pulsar is running standalone in a docker container. The docker compose file is as follows:
version: '3'

services:
  pulsar:
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar
    container_name: pulsar
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 6650:6650
      - 8080:8080
    command: bin/pulsar standalone

I am using the nuget package DotPulsar to try to connect to the Pulsar container. A consumer is created in the following code:
using DotPulsar;
using DotPulsar.Abstractions;
using DotPulsar.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class PulsarConsumer
{  
        protected IPulsarClient PulsarMessageClient { get; set; }

        public PulsarConsumer()
        {
            PulsarMessageClient = PulsarClient.Builder()
                .Build();
        }

        public async void Open()
        {
            Task.Run(async () => await ConsumeMessagesAsync());
        }

        private async Task ConsumeMessagesAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var subscription = $"Consumer_TEST";
                var consumer = PulsarMessageClient.NewConsumer()
                    .SubscriptionName(subscription)
                    .Topic($"persistent://public/default/TEST")
                    .Create();
                await foreach (var message in consumer.Messages())
                {
                    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message.Data.FirstSpan.ToArray());
                    if (data is not null)
                    {
                        // business logic
                    }

                    // Acknowledge the message
                    await consumer.Acknowledge(message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // exception handling
            }
        }
}

PulsarConsumer is instantiated somewhere else and then Open is called which will run the ConsumeMessagesAsync task.
This produces the following logging in the Pulsar container:
[pulsar-io-18-3] WARN  org.apache.pulsar.common.protocol.PulsarHandler - [[id: 0xe8c9aadc, L:/xxx.xx.x.3:6650 - R:/xxx.xx.x.1:54394]] Pulsar Handshake was not completed within timeout, closing connection
[pulsar-io-18-3] INFO  org.apache.pulsar.broker.service.ServerCnx - Closed connection from /xxx.xx.x.1:54394

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.
I also wrote a test app in .NET 6.0 using basically the exact same code and the actual same container and there it works perfectly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
